# Unable to add custom list item using SPServices

Tags: spservices

I'm testing a basic insert new list item to custom list  when user landed sub-sub site.

JS libraries are both reference in master page and path work perfectly.
First I'm getting Synchronous XMLHttpRequest warning and the list is not updating.

Would appreciate any help. TIA.

```
    function res_scr(val) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        webURL: "http://portal/lists",
        async: false,
        batchCmd: "New",
        listName: "MyPortalAwards",
       valuepairs: [["Title", val]],                
       completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
         if (status == "success") {
            console.log("Data Saved! and Please check your List");
         }
         else {
            console.log("Unable to submit your request at this time.");
         }
        }
    });
}




$( document ).ready(function() {

    if(window.location.href.indexOf("PoliciesCircularsMemo") >= 0)  {

        res_scr('RES-POLI-CIRC-MEMO');
    }

});
```

Comment: The script run with webURL set to root site. webURL:"/";

Answer (score 1):

The script you have written is for creating new list item. To update the list items use the below code:

```
$(divId).html(waitMessage).SPServices({
operation: "UpdateListItems",
listName: testList,
ID: ID,
valuepairs: [["Title", now]],
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    var out = $().SPServices.SPDebugXMLHttpResult({
        node: xData.responseXML,
        outputId: divId
    });
    $(divId).html("").append("<b>This is the output from the UpdateListItems operation:</b>" + out);
    $(divId).append("<b>Refresh to see the change in the list above.</b>");
}
});
```

[SPServices site reference](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UpdateListItems&referringTitle=Lists)

Also you can easily find other examples. The important part--ID is required while updating the items.

Comment: Apology for the confusion, I wanted to insert new item in the root list but I'm getting the error. Was also thinking that it will not work since the script triggered in sub-sub site where the list "MyPortalAwards" don't exist.

Appreciate the link though.

Comment: You should look into another parameter of SPServices "webUrl". Using this   you could achieve your functionality.

Comment: Added the webURL: "http://portal/lists" but it giving 500 error. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the correct operation and batchCmd. You need to remove the word lists from your webURL. Then you need to change your status variable to Status with a capital S.

```
function res_scr(val) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        webURL: "http://portal",
        async: false,
        batchCmd: "New",
        listName: "Announcements",
       valuepairs: [["Title", val]],                
       completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
         if (Status == "success") {
            console.log("Data Saved! and Please check your List");
         }
         else {
            console.log("Unable to submit your request at this time.");
         }
        }
    });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("PoliciesCircularsMemo") >= 0)  {
        res_scr('RES-POLI-CIRC-MEMO');
    }
});
```